# read excel file which has = in a column in r

Tags: r

I have an excel sheet which has formulas in one column like **C=(A-32)/1.8**. if i read using function read_excel it is showing the error as unexpected symbol in column. Need help in reading this.

Comment: Are these fatal errors or just warnings? `read_excel` often generates many notices as it is reading in a file, but did still successfully complete the operation.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/column-names.html).

Comment: It is an error and not completing the operation. Not warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to force each column type with the argument `col_types =` of the function `read_excel()` in the package **readxl**. You can specify the type `character` which should read the cells as they are.